# Check if $_GET superglobal variable is set and not equal to

Tags: php, get, isset

How do I check if `$_GET` superglobal variable is set and when it doesn't equal `0-100-euro`?

Unsuccessful example:

```
if( !isset($_GET['preis'] ) AND $_GET['preis'] === "0-100-euro" );
```

Comment: `$_GET['preis']!="0-100-euro"`

Comment: *"If is not set __and__ is a certain value..."* - Read this again slowly...

Comment: impossible is nothing, they told me..

Comment: glad it worked, now stop abusing people helping you for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$_GET['preis'] != "0-100-euro"
```

Right now, you try to see if the variable does not exist AND if it contains "0-100-euro". It will always return false. Just change `==` by `!=`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for this:

```
if($_GET['preis'] !== "0-100-euro") {
    echo "your message";
}
```

Comment: @MatthiasMüller yes abusing us for your poor English will get you far

Comment: Yes the second one but Alexandre TryHard Leblanc was first ^^

Answer (score 2):

I think that it is better to check if a key exists, because if you use "isset()" PHP can return a notice message: "Undefined index".

```
<?php

if (!array_key_exists('preis', $_GET) || $_GET['preis'] !== '0-100-euro') {
    die('"preis" is not set or is equal to "0-100-euro".');
}
```

Comment: Too many `===`, should be just `!=`. Interesting idea, though!

Answer (score 1):

Use `OR`, not `AND`, and reverse the test of the value.

```
if (!isset($_GET['preis') || $_GET['preis' != '0-100-euro')
```

Don't they teach [deMorgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) any more?

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Why? There's no possible coercion that will make a difference with a string like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by using sleek shortcuts:

```
isset( $_GET['preis'] ) && ( isset($_GET['preis'] ) && $_GET['preis'] != "0-100-euro" ) ? $result = true : $result = false;
```

Later you can check your request and in case it's not what you wanted, it will print:

```
isset( $result ) && print ( "0-100-euro is not set" );
```